# How content-addressing works in IPFS

Tags: ipfs

How to locate data in distributed network which is based on IPFS protocol if I don't know the hash value of that data.

I am new to IPFS. I know a little bit about IPFS and how it works. I came to know that IPFS is protocol which is content-addressed and user can retrieve the data by specifying the hash value of that data.

In a distributed network how will the 2nd user will be knowing the hash value of some data that 1st user added to the IPFS.

I went through some resources and IPFS site and came to know that it works on Distributed Hash Tables. But I am still not clear.

Please help me with the topic.

Comment: Much of the basics you can learn at https://proto.school. However, the core of your question seems to be how to locate data without knowing the hash. Do you have the data already, and want to see if someone else does? Or do you have partial data, and want to find full? Or do you want to do a search engine style, that finds all partial matches and related data? These clarifications will help much in determining the right answer.

Comment: My main question is how to locate the data without knowing the hash value of that data.

Comment: How are you identifying the data you are looking for? Do you have a copy already?